# jQuery Dialog Only Shows First Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Having a jQuery dialog issue.  I want to leverage ajax to render calendar content in a dialog window when a person clicks the the calDayContentEntry div.  The following code works on the first click, but after closing the dialog I can no longer get the dialog to show again for that entry.  Other entries work the first time as well, but secondary clicks will not open the dialog again.

Here is relevant code that I am having the issue with (all within the same asp.net mvc 3 razor view).  Does anyone have some tweaks that could fix this issue?

```
           ...
           <div class="calDayContent">
            @foreach (var content in day.Contents)
            {
                <div class="calDayContentEntry">
                    <input type="hidden" value="@content.Entry.Id" class="hiddenId" />   
                    <div class="@content.DisplayClass">@content.Entry.Hours.ToString() hrs</div>
                </div>
                <div class="leaveRequestPopup"></div>
            }
            </div>
           ...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.calDayContentEntry').click(function () {
            getAndShowDialogContents(this);
        });

        // Register close event for dialog if overlay is clicked
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
            //Close the dialog 

            $currentDialog.dialog("close");
        });
    });

    function getAndShowDialogContents(entryDiv) {

        var entryId = $(entryDiv).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
        var contentdiv = $(entryDiv).next('.leaveRequestPopup');
        var x = $(entryDiv).position().left + jQuery(entryDiv).outerWidth();
        var y = $(entryDiv).position().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Request/GetCalendarDetails',
            data: { id: entryId },
            success: function (result) {

                $(contentdiv).html(result);

                $(contentdiv).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Details',
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300,
                    draggable: false
                });

                $(contentdiv).dialog("option", "position", [x, y]);
                $currentDialog = $(contentdiv).dialog('open');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the weekend added a fresh perspective on the issue.  The code that works is below.  Basically, instead of using a popup div for every entry, I just used one div at the end of my page.  That div is reused for every dialog.  I use the global variable so I can refer to it when someone clicks outside the dialog to close it.  Hope this helps someone else out.

```
           ...
            <div class="calDayContent">
            @foreach (var content in day.Contents)
            {
                <div class="calDayContentEntry">
                    <input type="hidden" value="@content.Entry.Id" class="hiddenId" />

                        <div class="@content.DisplayClass">@content.Entry.Hours.ToString() hrs</div>
                </div>
            }
            </div>
            ...
            <div class="leaveRequestPopup"></div>
            ...


<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.calDayContentEntry').click(function () {
            getAndShowDialogContents(this);
        });

        // Register close event for dialog if overlay is clicked
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
            //Close the dialog 

            $currentDialog.dialog("close");
        });

        $currentDialog = $('.leaveRequestPopup').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Details',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            draggable: false
        });
    });

    function getAndShowDialogContents(entryDiv) {

        var entryId = $(entryDiv).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
        var x = $(entryDiv).position().left + jQuery(entryDiv).outerWidth();
        var y = $(entryDiv).position().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Request/GetCalendarDetails',
            data: { id: entryId },
            success: function (result) {

                $currentDialog.html(result);

                $currentDialog.dialog("option", "position", [x, y]);
                $currentDialog.dialog('open');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a valid statement?

```
$currentDialog.dialog("close");
```

I think that at this point it is out of scope.

Maybe if you define it outside before the $().ready

```
var $currentDialog;
$().ready(function () {
  ...
```

Comment: It's a global var in this case so it's in scope. Still not a good thing to be doing though.

Comment: I use the global variable so I have access to the dialog when the overlay is clicked which allows users to click anywhere on the page to close the dialog.  If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.  I posted my resolution to this issue, if you could correct the global variable usage with that solution, it would be highly appreciated, I just don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the dialog.

```
contentdiv.dialog("destroy").dialog(....
```

Note: if you do

```
 var contentdiv = $(entryDiv).next('.leaveRequestPopup');
```

then contentdiv is already a jQuery object so you say something like:

```
contentdiv.click(function(){
  //code here
});
```

You don't need to wrap it in $(contentdiv) again.

when you call this function:

```
getAndShowDialogContents(this);
```

It will pass as argument the raw document object, not a jQuery one, use:

```
getAndShowDialogContents($(this));
```

to pass the current jQuery object

Comment: I think that there is a syntax error there with double period.

Comment: Thanks, anyway you helped more to notice the typo then the ones that voted down for a snippet of code that (without the typo) works

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I missed where in my code I call destroy.  Will I destroy it in my ajax success function before the dialog creation?

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about passing jQuery objects around.  I should know better, I will fix my code appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I solved my issue and posted the full solution.  I was trying to use multiple divs in my solution when I only needed to reuse a single div.  The original divs were being lost and I could not reuse them.